# asp.net core not Dependency Injecting .net framework 4.5.1 libraries

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

i have a legacy application that has WCF as its entry point and it dependency injects interface created in .net framework 4.5.1 project. i am trying to replace wcf layer with asp.net core and when i try to dependency inject using asp.net core's default DI i get

> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, xxxx is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

I tried this with Asp.net core 2.2 with target framework 4.6.1 and also with asp.net core 2.1 where target framework is set to .net core 2.1

my DI setup in asp.net core looks like this

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSingleton<ITradeBusinessService, TradeBusinessService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUnityContainer, UnityContainer>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICommonDataRepository, CommonDataRepository>();
    }
```

this service TradeBusinessService takes in IUnityContainer in constructor.

```
        public TradeBusinessService(IUnityContainer objectContainer)
    {
        container = objectContainer;
        commonRepository = container.Resolve<ICommonDataRepository>();
```

and when i try to resolve ICommonDataRepository i get the error above.

ICommonDataRepository is in a project that is targeting 4.5.1

any ideas what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`UnityContainer` is just another DI framework like `Dependency Injection` of Asp.net Core. Why do you need both? Anyway, the problem is that you constracting new and empty unity container and inject it in `TradeBusinessService`. It doesn't have `ICommonDataRepository` type registered in it. My advice, get rid of `UnityContainer` and just inject `ICommonDataRepository` in `TradeBusinessService` directly.

Comment: Problem is that the legacy code has it like this but ill try to follow your suggestion. Will reply in a but

Comment: I don't know how your legacy code using Unity and what the cost of replacing it. The second approach can be initialize UnityContainer exactly as it was in legacy code and inject the instance and not the type in DI. This way your TradeBusinessService will receive initialized unity container. You just need to understand, that registering something in `services` won't register in unity, because it different containers.

Comment: you hit the nail. actually i need this second approach. the existing thing is a WCF service that has its web.config and all DI services and their mapping are mentioned in it. I want to initialize a UnityContainer using that web.config and pass it in asp.net core's mapping. if that not possible i can write mapping code in asp.net core to initialize this UnityContainer. you have any code snippet that can do that ?

Comment: i was thinking something like this 

   var container = new UnityContainer();
            services.AddSingleton<IUnityContainer>(container);
now i need to tell this "container" object that where is the web.config file to picks its mappings from. something around these lines.

Comment: Not enough information in how you are using unity right now. Is it registered as Resolver on http pipeline? Do you have a static/singleton instance of container and calling Resolve from any place you want? Do you inject IUnityContainer and then resolve manually all types you need? I beleave you have a mix of all of them. It should be long post to cover the solution.